# If $A=\{a,b,c\}$ be any Set and $R$ is a relation on $A$ and $R = \{(b,c)\}\;,$ Then Relation $R$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $A=\{a,b,c\}$ be any Set and $R$ is a relation on $A$ and $R = \{(b,c)\}\;,$ Then Relation $R$ is
>
> $\bf{Options::}$  $(a)\;$ Reflexive $\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;$ Symmetric $\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;$ Transitive $\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;$ Equivalence

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ A Relation $R$ on Set $A$ is Said to be Reflexive, If $(x,x)\; \forall\;  x\in A.$

A Relation $R$ on Set $A$ is Said to be Transitive, If $(x,y)\in R\Rightarrow (y,x)\in R.$

A Relation $R$ on Set $A$ is Said to be Transitive, If $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in A,$ Then $(x,z)\in A\;,$

Where $(x,y,z)\in A$.

So Here above relation $R$ is not Reflexive, Bcz $(x,x)\not \in R$ for all $x\in A$

and It is Not Symmetric Bcz $(b,c)\in R$ But $(c,b)\notin R$

So It is Not an equivalence Relation.

But I did not Understand How can we check its Transitivity,

Help me , Thanks

Comment: be careful because in set notation order doesn't matter and $(b,c)$ is the same as $(c,b)$ 

Furthermore, what operation are you even using on that set ?

Comment: @alkabary $(b,c)$ is not set notation. It is an ordered pair, so $(b,c)\ne (c,b)$.

Comment: If $A$ is any set, then $b$ may equal $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is transitive. In logic the statement $p \rightarrow q$ is true when $p$ is false irrespective of $q$.

Here $p$ can be seen as $(b\mathbf{R}c) \land (c\mathbf{R}z)$ which is not a valid boolean (is false). In addition, $q$ can be viewd as $(a\mathbf{R}z)$.

In fact, for proving transitivity you need to prove that $p \rightarrow q$ is true which is the case here since $p$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

A statement like "if $A$ then $B$" is considered true in mathematics if $A$ is not true.  So, because there is no pair $(x,y),(y,z)\in R$, the relation is considered to be transitive.